# Uploading a file using validated data

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel I have a simple function that stores a job listing in my database.

Initially, it looked like this:

```
/**
 * Store a new instance of a job posting in the database
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return void
 */
public function store(StoreJobPost $request)
{
    $job = new JobPost();

    $job->position = $request->get('position');
    $job->description = $request->get('description');
    $job->location = $request->get('location');
    $job->business_area = $request->get('business_area');
    $job->contract_type = $request->get('contract_type');
    $job->hours = $request->get('hours');
    $job->salary = $request->get('salary');
    $job->salary_period = $request->get('salary_period');
    $job->attached_description = $request->get('attached_description');
    $job->scheme = $request->get('scheme');
    $job->contact_name = $request->get('contact_name');
    $job->contact_email = $request->get('contact_email');
    $job->contact_number = $request->get('contact_number');
    $job->status = $request->get('status');
    $job->expires_on = $request->get('expires_on');

    $job->save();

    return redirect()->route('vacancies.index')->with('success', 'Job listing created successfully');
}
```

I shortened it to look like this:

```
/**
 * Store a new instance of a job posting in the database
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return void
 */
public function store(StoreJobPost $request)
{
    $validFormData = $request->validated();

    $job = JobPost::create($validFormData);

    return redirect()->route('vacancies.index')->with('success', 'Job listing created successfully');
}
```

However, I want to also store a file. Previously I have done something like this:

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$path = $file->storeAs('library/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

At which point I've had:

```
$object->path = $path;
$object->save();
```

In the current scenario is it possible to get the file back from `$validatedFormData` so that I can store the path to the upload in the database with the rest of the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes sure. Do this:

```
public function store(StoreJobPost $request)
{
    $validFormData = $request->validated();

    $file = $request->file('file');
    $path = $file->storeAs('library/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
    $validFormData['path']= $path;

    $job = JobPost::create($validFormData);

    return redirect()->route('vacancies.index')->with('success', 'Job listing created successfully');
}
```

Comment: Is it really that simple? Damn

Comment: Also if you're using StoreJobPost to validate your request, you probably use $request directly as the data will be already validated, no need to use an extra array "validFormData" unless it is for name organization

Comment: No @LuisTerrero, the file path is not available in the request. That's why it must be added. Hope you get it.

Comment: You're right Elisha, the file path won't be, but I was referring to the rest of the data that I'm assuming already was validated when going through StoreJobPost

Comment: Ok Luis, that will be fine.